# Restriction enzyme type II

Tags: molecular-biology, dna, restriction-enzymes

Why can't a type II restriction enzyme cut a nucleic acid with the following base composition:

> A: 28% C: 15% G: 35% T: 22%

Comment: I don't really get your question... First, a restriction enzyme cut at recognition site, I never heard about base content distribution (can you link a source?) Second, in any DNA sequence the percentage of A is equal to the percentage of T and the same is true for C and G. What king of DNA sequence can have 28%T and 22%T? So it must be RNA you are talking about. But then T is not correct, it should be U. Please add more details to your question.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. To me, this seems like a [homework question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) (those are off-topic here, see link) so I put a flag to it. Please show some effort to answering the question yourself, if you want to avoid the question being deleted/closed. What do you know about the enzyme? What dies the base composition tell you about the sequence in question? Basically, let us know that you are trying. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is a homework, not a genuine curiosity. That being the case, I'm gonna give you two different answers here: the standard one, which is the one I believe your teacher/lecturer expects to see, and a more complicated one in the *addendum*.

The first thing that draws out attention in the question is the base percentages. Clearly, it doesn't follow the famous Watson-Crick pairing rule (A pairs with T, G pairs with C) and, because of that, we don't see the [Chargaff's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chargaff%27s_rules) in this nucleic acid.

Thus, this is not a double-stranded DNA (dsDNA), but a **single-stranded DNA** (ssDNA).

That being said, the answer to that question can be something along these lines:

> A Type II RE can't cut that nucleic acid because that is a ssDNA.

**Addendum:**

There is a complication here, which may render the previous answer questionable.

[Type II Restriction Enzymes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_enzyme) only cleave *regular*, that is, double-stranded DNAs. So, they cannot cleave ssDNAs, which corroborates the answer we just gave.

But the problem is that ssDNAs can form loop structures, in which there is pairing between bases in the same strand. In those structures, DNA is technically dsDNA and, as such, can be cleaved by Type II RE. For instance, have a look at this paper:
[Type II restriction endonucleases cleave single-stranded DNAs in general](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC321909/).

That being said, Type II RE do, in fact, cleave ssDNA (in places where ssDNA form loops and structurally resembles a dsDNA), which makes the question itself meaningless.

Comment: It is in fact a homework, the base percentage could only be possible if it refers to a ssDNA. Therefore, could the answer be anything related with palindromes? Although we cant say anything about the recognition site

Comment: I think that it is worth explaining that, at least according to the paper that is referred to in the answer, the observed cutting of a single-stranded phage DNA is due to the formation of dsDNA in stem-loop structures. This may seem pedantic, but clearly, from the point of view of the restriction enzymes, the substrate is still dsDNA.